# Internal server error - Authorization Filter Attribute - Xamarin.forms

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

having custom class inherited from AuthorizationFilterAttribute abstract class.
Here i override the following function like this,

```
public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var request = actionContext.Request;
        var user = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal;
```

Through postman, i can hit this class. but through Android couldn't.

In Android, having custom class inherited from DelegatingHandler class.
Here i override the following function like this,

```
 protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Clone the request, in case we need to re-issue it
        var clone = await CloneHttpRequestMessageAsync(request);
        // Now do the request
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

the response will be always "Internal server error". it happened in Mobile App server in Azure portal.

For development purpose i have created and it is working fine still. But i created new one for same development one, it doesn't work. There is a problem like "Internal server error".

Please let me know if the provided information is not enough. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Internal server error` What is the problem that is reported in the server log?

Comment: error message: "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. " and response.Statuscode is InternaleServerError.

Comment: PID[8160] Critical    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.EasyAuthModule.<HydrateTokenStoreUserClaimsAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.EasyAuthModule.<AuthenticateAsync>d__24.MoveNext()

Comment: End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.EasyAuthModule.<OnAuthenticateRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext()

Comment: End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.HttpModuleDispatcher.<DispatchAsync>d__10.MoveNext()